# Javascript scroll does not have effect on Android WebView and browser

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have a WebView in Android. The content displays a html page, but when it tries to execute this script, nothing really happens (the //DO SOMETHING is never invoked):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mid-table').scroll(function(evt) {
        // DO SOMETHING
        });
});
```

I tried directly from the browser of the same mobile (Galaxy S), and nothing happens as well.

It works perfectly on IOS or from Firefox, Explorer... , but here it doesn't.

any clue?